# can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' Pandas Matplotlib Pie-Chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pie-chart

I was trying to create a Pie Chart with the help of pandas and matplotlib.

This table looks like:
[mushroom_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU7wn.png)

I have a for loop that tranverses each column in the columns list. For every column i am to create a pie chart ( every column contains only categorical variables ).

```
columns = df.columns.tolist()

for column in columns:
    wedge_sizes = df[column].value_counts()
    wedge_sizes = [i / df[column].count() for i in wedge_sizes]
    print(type(df[column].unique()[0]))
    plt.pie(wedge_sizes,df[column].unique())
    plt.title(df[column])
    plt.axis("equal")
    plt.show()
    plt.clf()
```

The Problem is in the line `plt.pie(wedge_sizes,df[column].unique())`. I get an error: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'.

I am sure there is a problem with the `df[column].unique()` because without it, the code works and i do not get any errors, but i get a pie-charts without any labels. I tried not only `df[column].unique()` but `df[column].value_counts().index`.
As the second value in `plt.pie()` there are labels so only the array with unique values of a column is needed.

Comment: From docs, the second argument seems to be "explode", not "labels".